# Python syntax error after using multiple print functions

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error

I have just begun teaching myself Python for a project I am working on.
This may be a fairly rookie question, but is there a limit to the number of times you can use the Print function? My code is using Print to request input from the user, however a syntax error (invalid syntax) appears at the 6th instance. As far as I can tell there are no mistakes in/around the line.
I am using Python 3.4.4.

The problem line is;

```
print('What is the isentropic efficiency of the intake?')
```

The whole exert from the code is;

```
# Define cycle
print('What is the cruise altitude (m)?')
altitude = float(input())
print('What is the cruise Mach number?')
print('What is the mass flow?')
W = float(input())
mach0 = float(input())
print('What is the OPR?')
OPR = float(input())
print('What is the TET?')
TET = float(input())
gamma = 1.4
Cp = 1000

# Calculate the freestream properties based on ISA
if altitude < 11000:
    t0 = 288.15 - (6.5*(altitude/1000))
    p0 = 101325*((1-(0.0065*(altitude/288.15)))**5.2561)
else:
    t0 = 288.15 - (6.5*11)
    p0 = (101325*((1-(0.0065*(11000/288.15)))**5.2561))*math.exp((-9.80665*(altitude-11000))/(287.04*t0))

# Calculate Intake Performance

T0 = t0*(1+(((gamma-1)/2)*(mach0**2)))
P0 = p0*((T0/t0)**(gamma/(gamma-1))

print('What is the isentropic efficiency of the intake?')

eta_intake = float(input())
T2 = T0*(1+(((gamma-1)/2)*eta_intake*(mach0**2)))
P2 = P0*((T2/T0)**(gamma/(gamma-1))
```

Comment: You may want to use an editor that can match parentheses for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no limit to how many times can you use any function in Python. The error is not caused by the line with the `print` statement.
The previous line is missing a closing parenthesis. It should be like that:

```
P0 = p0*((T0/t0)**(gamma/(gamma-1)))

print('What is the isentropic efficiency of the intake?')
```